# Differences between OSGEO GDAL and GDAL python bindings?

Tags: gdal, python-3, osgeo

#### Question

I'm trying to figure what are the differences, and of course, what is the best solution to use, between two [python3](https://www.python.org/) [bindings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding):

- GDAL, imported as `import gdal`
- OSGEO.GDAL, imported as `from osgeo import gdal`

Indeed, here are the results of some commands such as [`.__file__`](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/two_dunders.html) and [`.__version__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/) methods for both of them;

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.    

>>> import gdal
>>> gdal.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gdal.py'
>>> gdal.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'gdal' has no attribute '__version__'    

>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> gdal.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py'
>>> gdal.__version__
'2.4.0'
>>>
```

#### Environment and informations

Ubuntu `5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux`
`Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)`

```
$ pip3 list | grep -i gdal
GDAL                          2.4.0
```

```
$ pip3 list | grep -i osgeo
(empty result)
```

```
$ apt-cache search gdal | grep -i python
python-rasterio - Python 2 API for using geospatial raster data with Numpy
python-stetl - Streaming ETL - Geospatial ETL framework for Python 2
python3-csvkit - public modules for csvkit (Python 3)
python3-rasterio - Python 3 API for using geospatial raster data with Numpy
python3-gdal - Python 3 bindings to the Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
python-gdal - Python bindings to the Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
```

```
$ apt-cache search osgeo
python-geolinks - Python 2 Library for using geospatial links (catalogue interoperablity)
python3-geolinks - Python 3 Library for using geospatial links (catalogue interoperablity)
pycsw - OGC compliant metadata (Catalogue Service for the Web) server
pycsw-doc - OGC compliant metadata (Catalogue Service for the Web) server - documentation
pycsw-wsgi - WSGI Apache CSW service based on pycsw
python-pycsw - OGC compliant metadata (Catalogue Service for the Web) server - Python 2
python-pycsw-doc - Transitional dummy package to pycsw-doc
python-pycsw-wsgi - Transitional dummy package to pycsw-wsgi
python3-pycsw - OGC compliant metadata (Catalogue Service for the Web) server - Python 3
```

I don't know from where do both packages come from at this point (e.g. which was installed by `apt` or `pip`).

#### Links

[Difference between osgeo gdal/ogr python module and GDAL C++ library](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136160/difference-between-osgeo-gdal-ogr-python-module-and-gdal-c-library)
https://gdal.org/
https://www.osgeo.org/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As documented in https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/ plain "gdal" is deprecated and you should not use that for writing any new code

> Additionally, there are five compatibility modules that are included
> but provide notices to state that they are deprecated and will be
> going away. If you are using GDAL 1.7 bindings, you should update your
> imports to utilize the usage above [from osgeo import gdal], but the following will work until
> at least GDAL 2.1.
>
> import gdal
>
> import ogr
>
> import osr
>
> import gdalnumeric
>
> import gdalconst

Since GDAL 2.0, published in 2015, the right way to import is

```
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> from osgeo import ogr
>>> from osgeo import osr
>>> from osgeo import gdal_array
>>> from osgeo import gdalconst
```