# import gdal vs import osgeo.gdal

Tags: python, gdal

I recently had to reinstall my conda environment on Linux. I installed from my old `environment.yml` file, and it picked up the following gdal versions:

```
$ conda list|grep gdal
gdal                      3.2.1            py38hc0b2d6b_7    conda-forge
libgdal                   3.2.1                h38ff51b_7    conda-forge
```

These is fairly recent, but in 3.2.0, import as gdal [was removed](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.2.1/gdal/NEWS)

```
Python bindings: old-style "import gdal" is no longer available.
Use "from osgeo import gdal" instead
```

I have tons of code that use `import gdal`, and it's just time consuming catching all instances `import gdal` and change them to `from osgeo import gdal`. Is there some way to automate this (other than using `find` and editing things by hand?)

Comment: sed 's/import gdal/from osgeo import gdal/'

Comment: In hindsight, this is what I was trying to avoid: some packages are installed locally, some for some environments, some are being developed... So I'd rather have to go fixing all these issues one by one.

Comment: Do you believe there is something that prevents the mass edit? Syntax `from osgeo import gdal` has been supported for years.

Comment: Check this out, it may help ;-) : [Differences between OSGEO GDAL and GDAL python bindings?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347504/differences-between-osgeo-gdal-and-gdal-python-bindings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest hack is to add the [`gdal.py`](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/release/3.1/gdal/swig/python/gdal.py) scripts (and `ogr.py` and `osr.py`) convenience imports from the historic GDAL distribution somewhere towards the top of the PYTHONPATH.

This is a better solution for multi-user systems than editing all the source code, as if this invocation of gdal is common throughout complex codebases, it's hard to find all occurrences.