# Import Errors: fiona and gdal

Tags: python, gdal, fiona

I can neither import **fiona** nor **gdal**.

I installed the following Python version:

```
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Furthermore I installed the following :**numpy, shapely, gdal, and fiona** and am using Spyder for coding. Also I installed Visual Studio to be able to run C++.

I used pip to install numpy and shapely. For gdal I downloaded `GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27` from: [https://www.gisinternals.com/archive.php](https:///www.gisinternals.com/archive.php)

I have added some environmental variables to windows for gdal, not sure if they are correct. While trying to solve the import problem I added more and more at different places...

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have installed `Fiona 1.8.21` with the **Fiona-1.8.21-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl** from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona) using pip install.

So now my problem.

When I try to first import fiona, then that's the output:

```
import fiona
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\AN\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4032\1102285635.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    import fiona

  File "c:\users\an\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection

  File "c:\users\an\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 11, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ogrext: The specified module could not be found.
```

When I first try to import gdal, error no module named gdal occurs. When I then try to import fiona the following errors occur:

```
import gdal

  File "C:\Users\AN\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4032\3648793768.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    import gdal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
```

```
import fiona

  File "c:\users\an\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
    with fiona._loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should probably import gdal this way: `from osgeo import gdal`. See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/347504/65370).

Comment: @swiss_knight : importing osgeo works fine, but however it doesn't help me to import gdal, I get the following error `ImportError: cannot import name 'gdal' from 'osgeo' (unknown location)`